# Regex to match only the first listed item in a block of HTML

Tags: regex

My CMS allows PHP keyword replacements, and I'm currently building a format to return the first listed item element in a data field which usually contains a HTML unordered list, but can often contain paragraphs, etc.

If possible, I'd like to use a regular expression to match only the first listed item element `li` in a returned block, and print it.

One severe limitation, is that I cannot use the `^` character as my CMS (annoyingly) uses that character for modification functions.

So far, I've only come up with: `replace:<\/li>.*:</li></ul>` - but this is only replacing the first listed item's closing tag in a returned block. What I really need is something like:

```
replace:anything_that's_not_first_li_element:nothing
```

I appreciate that this question is a very long shot, so thanks in advance for all constructive responses.

Comment: Does it allow group references like `$1` or `\1` in the replacement string?

Comment: As far as I know, it's based on PHP regex capabilities, the only limitation being no use of `^`

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex with the `s` flag.

```
(?<=<ul>).*?<li>.*?<\/li>
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/hL1zF0

PHP:

```
$list = '<ul>
<li>first</li>
<li>second</li>
<li>third</li>
<li>fourth</li>
</ul>';

preg_match('/(?<=<ul>).*?<li>.*?<\/li>/s', $list, $matches);

echo $matches[0];
```

Output:

```
<li>first</li>
```

Comment: @Bohemian, yes. The `s` flag is the dotall flag. (or otherwise known as singleline flag).   It's in my answer. :)